# Magento 2 to add link with current url as href inside head section

Tags: magento2, header

need to add alternative link in head with current URL as Href.
example

```
<link  rel="aletrnative" href="{current page url}" />
```

[image]

Comment: You just want to get current page url right?

Comment: yeah in  /layout/default_head_blocks.xml block

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can add `<link href="...">` by creating new `phtml` template.
Example:
In `your_layout.xml` file,

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="YourCompany_YourModule::head_links.phtml" />
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
</page>
```

In `templates/head_links.phtml`,

```
<link href="{your url}" />
```

After that, don't forget to `bin/magento cache:clean`. It'll work.